# How to redirect wordpress website with ssl to non-www from www running on azure?

Tags: wordpress, azure, redirect, web-config, no-www

I am running a website, computergk.com hosted on windows azure and ssl (from windows azure) installed on it.

I want to redirect the www version of the website to non-www. How can this be done?

The existing web.config configuration is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://computergk.com" 
patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have already forwarded www cname record of my domain to @. I am using Windows Azure SSL provided by Godaddy Class 2 Certification Authority.

Answer (score 0):

Open .htaccess and add this line

```
RewriteEngine On
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.computergk\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://computergk.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect http to https all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://computergk.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: There is no .htaccess file. There is web.config file.